# Avoiding IORefs in pure code

Tags: haskell, data-structures, monads, union-find, ioref

I noticed that [Data.UnionFind](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/union-find) uses the IO monad to provide pointers via IORefs. I imagine everyone happily calls `unsafePerformIO` when using it locally in pure code, since the data structure is so well understood, but ..

Is there a canonical cleaner approach to such data structures?  Perhaps a wrapper around IO that makes the inevitable `unsafePerformIO` less unsafe "looking" by prohibiting most IO operations?

Comment: I believe that package is intended to be used inside the IO monad. Most Haskellers stay as far away from `unsafePerformIO` as possible.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is there a canonical cleaner approach to such data structures? Perhaps a wrapper around IO that makes the inevitable unsafePerformIO less unsafe "looking" by prohibiting most IO operations?

Yes, precisely. You have just invented [**the ST monad**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html), introduced by [Launchbury and Peyton Jones](http://www.cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/lazy-functional-state-threads.pdf) some 20 years ago.

The `ST` monad allows only locally-scoped memory effects. It is remarkable in that it uses the type system to guarantee that side effects are not visible outside of the scope of the code block that is using them.

So, as long as you use memory only via references, only in local scope, you can avoid `unsafePerformIO` and use pure ST instead, for example, to [implement union-find](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/equivalence/0.2.3/doc/html/Data-Equivalence-STT.html).

Comment: The above ```ST monad``` link is broken. Here's the current one: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html